# Eclipse and Feature-based launching - feature not showing up in "about"

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am using [feature-based launching in Eclipse](http://blog.ankursharma.org/2010/04/feature-based-launching.html) to launch a new Eclipse process with a feature I have developed. The feature also seems to be enabled, i.e., the corresponding buttons etc. show up.

However, the feature does not show up in the "about" dialog. I am trying to debug the branding of the feature (logo etc.), so that is quite unfortunate. Is this a mistake on my side or intended behavior?

Comment: Where on the about dialog? Some things only show up when you build the product and run that.

Comment: It does not show up in the list of features. Also the branding icon does not show up in the list of icons.